# How to change texture based on Height / Slope of object

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, geometry

I would like to merge two different textures using an Shadermix node and for the factor to be based on the vertical slope of the geometry.

Basically I want the flatter areas of the model to be one texture and the vertical areas another. I dont know how to do this? Any thoughts / ideas.

Answer (score 8):

The direction that the geometry faces is its normal.  The up vector in the world is 0,0,1.  You can find the angle (in radians) between two unit-length vectors by taking the arccosine of the dot product of those two vectors.

Taking it all together, we can make something like this:

[image]

When the normal is facing in the +Z direction, there is no slope, and we're emitting green. As the slope increases, we mix with red emission.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Normal output of the *Texture Coordinate*, then put a *(Converter) > Separate XYZ* and use its Z output, now the color will depend on how the slot is close to Z:

[image]