# Slope mask for texturing

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders

I found this way for masking textures using a slope.
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/265439/105723

If it's just a basic shading it works fine
[image]
Mask
[image]

But I noticed it takes account of displacement and normals...
[image]
Mask
[image]

[image]

Is there a way to avoid that displacement and normal info and keep the first mask result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly to how you mix the color for the Principled BSDF you need to mix the displacements or the height map you use for the displacements.

[image: Mixing two different Displacement-nodes using a Mix-node]

Comment: I mixed the colors not the displacements, ok, I understand... Thanks!